# Login for internet use

Tags: apache2, dns

How to protect internet access using username and password. I mean that i need a situation, say when anyone opens a browser and trys to go for any site it would redirect to a login page for authentication. After login he/she can access any site. I am pretty sure that this kind of situation is common. How can implement it in ubuntu? Is it handled by apache or dns-server?

thanks in advance.

Edited:
As an example: in an university there are 100's of computers and 1000's of students. Sometimes it is become difficult to surf internet because of unnecessary download. To prevent download i want to track the bad students. So when anyone wants to access internet he/she has to login first so that i can track him/her.

Answer (score 1):

You really should provide more details, but in general these types of problems should be fixed on the router. That is, the router will accept clients, but will only forward traffic for clients on which a user has authenticated. Apache can be used to run the web application that enables the user to log in and then you'll likely use a script that configures iptables to forward traffic all traffic to that web ui.

Comment: i have edited the post. Hope you will understand what i want